# How can I add a hyperlink to a field contaning plain text?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, column

I'm using SP Foundation 2010, with severly limited development permissions. I'm operating as a site Owner in a user area, so access to Designer, Visual Studio, etc. is limited and I'm looking for solutions that can be accomplished with those constraints in mind.

We have a document library of about 2000 documents used by our help desk. Our SharePoint database contains the field `TITLE` which is the plain-english description (e.g., `Calulate Deposit Amount` and the field `NAME` which is the filename (e.g. `Calculate_Deposit_Amount_1204LB_.html`).

I want to DISPLAY `TITLE` but as a clickable link to `NAME`. If I were coding html, I'd use `<a href="NAME_FIELD_CONTENTS">TITLE_FIELD_CONTENTS</a></BR>`.

Any suggestions for doing that in SP? can that be accomplished with lookup fields/metadata filtering? or do I need to create a new site/page to house the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are 3 solutions..

### Adding that value as a SPFieldURLValue

```
SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue();
value.Description = "Display Value";
value.Url = "Your URL";
listItem["FieldName"] = value;
```

In this case, since the type of the "Title" field is text the value shown will be as..

> "Your URL, Display Value"

### Changing the "Title" field type to URL

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839308/create-a-custom-column-hyperlink-type-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2)

### Changing the "Title" field type to Note and enable Rich Text

[Creating an Enhanced Rich Text Field](http://leedale.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/creating-an-enhanced-rich-text-field-in-your-sharepoint-content-types/)

---

- Else just hide the Title Field and create a new field of type URL(Hyperlink)

[how-to-remove-title-column-from-sharepoint-list](http://www.dlocc.com/articles/how-to-remove-title-column-from-sharepoint-list/)